# I have an error when the code first tries to generate the code it says unable to determine the principal end of an association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

in EF Codefirst there is a middle table(Model) in my project like `:

```
public class ClientDriverLoad
{
    public ClientDriverLoad()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DriverLoad> DriverLoads { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

and Client that derives from it's parent Person:

```
public class Client:Person
{
    public virtual List<ClientDriverPayment> ClientPayments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ClientDriverLoad> ClientDriverLoad { get; set; }
}
```

and DriverLoad Model is like this :

```
 public class DriverLoad
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public virtual Load Load { get; set; }
    public string StartPoint { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public long price { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientDriverLoad ClientDriverLoad { get; set; }
}
```

and clientDriverPayment like this :

```
public class ClientDriverPayment
{
    public ClientDriverPayment() {
        DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public virtual Payment Payment { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

if searched a lot and figured I should use Fluent Api or something how should I determine what relationship should I Use could anyone help me please ?

Comment: Can you show the exact error message (it should contain relevant information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use these codes in your DbContext class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<ClientDriverLoad>().HasMany(m => m.DriverLoads).WithRequired(m => m.ClientDriverLoad);
        mb.Entity<ClientDriverPayment>().HasRequired(m => m.Client).WithMany(m => m.ClientPayments);
}
```